# Blank page in react after using navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a React app and it ran perfectly fine with simple HTML/CSS a header and a button. But when I added `<Routes>`, `<Route>` and navigation.navigate, I get a blank screen with no errors in the console that I used to run the app. However, there is an error in the browser console, stating "Cannot read property of undefined 'getElementById".

I have tried giving the main parent div id='root' as that is the variable that was passed to getElementById. I am not sure what other solutions to try as other questions have had different situations/contexts.

Sample code is here https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-fast-zqcn83?file=/src/index.js .
You can see the error message, and if you exit it, you can see the blank screen (with the colour that I chose).

Code:

```
import './App.css';
import {Routes, Route, Router, useNavigate, NavLink, Link, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Newpage from './screens/Newpage.js'

function App() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  function navigateToCloset(){
    navigate(Newpage);
  }

  const About = () => (
    <div className='about'>
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <p>Ipsum dolor dolorem consectetur est velit fugiat. Dolorem provident corporis fuga saepe distinctio ipsam? Et quos harum excepturi dolorum molestias?</p>
      <p>Ipsum dolor dolorem consectetur est velit fugiat. Dolorem provident corporis fuga saepe distinctio ipsam? Et quos harum excepturi dolorum molestias?</p>
    </div>
  );

  const Contact = () => (
    <div className='contact'>
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
      <p>You can reach me via email: <strong>hello@example.com</strong></p>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <div id='root'>
      <div className='header'>
        My Closet
      </div>
      <div className='homepagebuttondiv'>
        <button className='homepagebutton'
        onClick={navigateToCloset}
        >
          Enter Closet
        </button>
        <button className='homepagebutton'>
          New Clothing
        </button>
        </div>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="about" element={<About />}/>
          <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
    </Routes>

        <nav>
          {/* <Link to="/">home?</Link> */}
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </nav>



    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @seasons look at the error more closely, what line was it on? Does it tell you any more information if you imagine the error happening at that particular line? Also, try to reproduce it on a codesandbox and share it here.

Comment: Please provide your code or image so others can better understand and solve your problem!

Comment: add sample in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @Yuji'Tomita'Tomita It's in line 7 where the line ReactDOM.render((<App />).document.getElementById("root"));
 is

Comment: if you are just trying to navigate to a new page (a new url) then you should use react-router-dom. Usually you use 'useNavigate' to go back to a previous page. In addition, the argument you are passing to `useNavigate` shouldnt be a component, it should be a path or "navigate(-1)' to go back to a previous page. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to navigate to a different page?

If so try using react-router-dom

Here's the link to the documentation
https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/getting-started/tutorial.md

EDIT: You should use the changes that Agrim provided.
But i would also Add the `<Router>` to wrap the app. This is just a rename of BrowserRouter

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

I would also change the code in `App.js` to

```
import "./App.css";
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate,
  NavLink,
  Link,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Newpage from "./screens/Newpage.js";
// import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
// import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function App() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  function navigateToCloset() {
    navigate(Newpage);
  }

  const About = () => (
    <div className="about">
      <h1>About Me</h1>
      <p>
        Ipsum dolor dolorem consectetur est velit fugiat. Dolorem provident
        corporis fuga saepe distinctio ipsam? Et quos harum excepturi dolorum
        molestias?
      </p>
      <p>
        Ipsum dolor dolorem consectetur est velit fugiat. Dolorem provident
        corporis fuga saepe distinctio ipsam? Et quos harum excepturi dolorum
        molestias?
      </p>
    </div>
  );

  const Contact = () => (
    <div className="contact">
      <h1>Contact Me</h1>
      <p>
        You can reach me via email: <strong>hello@example.com</strong>
      </p>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div id="App">
      <div className="header">My Closet</div>
      <div className="homepagebuttondiv">
        <button className="homepagebutton" onClick={navigateToCloset}>
          Enter Closet
        </button>
        <button className="homepagebutton">New Clothing</button>
      </div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>

      <nav>
        {/* <Link to="/">home?</Link> */}
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yes I am, and I am indeed using react-router-dom. Just edited my post to contain the code!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `react@18.0.0` and `react-dom@18.0.0`?

If so, then use this code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

instead of this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render((<App />).document.getElementById("root"));
```

in `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest your button inside a link to navigate to a different page.

`App.js:`

```
return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div id="root">
        <nav>
          <div className="header">My Closet</div>
          <div className="homepagebuttondiv">
            <Link to="/new">
              <button className="homepagebutton">Enter Closet</button>
            </Link>
            <button className="homepagebutton">New Clothing</button>
          </div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="new" element={<Newpage />} />
            <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
          </Routes>

          {/* <Link to="/">home?</Link> */}
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

There is a typo in `index.js`. The `.` before "document" needs to be a `,` let me know if this works, I'm not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve. This is a 'bandaid' solution to your problem.  There are best practices in terms of creating a multi page website, in which your `app.js` should look something like:

```
function App() {
  return (<>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  </>
  );
}
```

To navigate around your app within those pages, you could use a navbar or use `Links` in your `home` and other components.